# Cassandra DC2 nodes down after increasing write requests on DC1 nodes

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

We are using Cassandra 2.1.2 in a multi dc cluster (30 servers on DC1 and 10 on DC2) with a key space replication factor of 1 on DC1 and 2 on DC2.

For some reason when we increase the volume of write requests on DC1 (using ONE or LOCAL_ONE), the cassandra java process on DC2 nodes goes down randomly.

At the time DC2 nodes starts to go down, the load average on DC1 nodes are around 3-5 and on DC2 around 7-10.. so not big deal.

**Taking a look at the Cassandra's system.log, we found some exceptions:**

```
ERROR [SharedPool-Worker-43] 2014-11-15 00:39:48,596 JVMStabilityInspector.java:94 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:8] 2014-11-15 00:39:48,596 CassandraDaemon.java:153 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:8,1,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
ERROR [Thrift-Selector_2] 2014-11-15 00:39:48,596 Message.java:238 - Got an IOException during write!
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:470) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TNonblockingSocket.write(TNonblockingSocket.java:164) ~[libthrift-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.util.mem.Buffer.writeTo(Buffer.java:104) ~[thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.util.mem.FastMemoryOutputTransport.streamTo(FastMemoryOutputTransport.java:112) ~[thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.Message.write(Message.java:222) ~[thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.TDisruptorServer$SelectorThread.handleWrite(TDisruptorServer.java:598) [thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.TDisruptorServer$SelectorThread.processKey(TDisruptorServer.java:569) [thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.TDisruptorServer$AbstractSelectorThread.select(TDisruptorServer.java:423) [thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
        at com.thinkaurelius.thrift.TDisruptorServer$AbstractSelectorThread.run(TDisruptorServer.java:383) [thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:na]
ERROR [Thread-94] 2014-11-15 00:39:48,597 CassandraDaemon.java:153 - Exception in thread Thread[Thread-94,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.duplicate(HeapByteBuffer.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType.sliceBytes(AbstractCType.java:369) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCompoundCellNameType.fromByteBuffer(AbstractCompoundCellNameType.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:397) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCType$Serializer.deserialize(AbstractCType.java:381) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCellNameType$5.deserialize(AbstractCellNameType.java:117) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.composites.AbstractCellNameType$5.deserialize(AbstractCellNameType.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserialize(ColumnSerializer.java:106) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserialize(ColumnSerializer.java:101) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilySerializer.deserialize(ColumnFamilySerializer.java:110) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserializeOneCf(Mutation.java:322) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserialize(Mutation.java:302) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserialize(Mutation.java:330) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Mutation$MutationSerializer.deserialize(Mutation.java:272) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageIn.read(MessageIn.java:99) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:168) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessages(IncomingTcpConnection.java:150) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:82) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.2.jar:2.1.2]
```

**Memory:**

- DC1 servers have 32 GB of RAM and the HEAP is configured to 8 GB.
- DC2 servers have 16 GB of RAM and the HEAP is also configured to 8 GB.

Please, any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the RF higher in DC2 with less machines and smaller machines?

Comment: @GQuintana, the DC2 is just used for "backup"/failover, all the writes and reads are always performed from DC1 nodes only.

Comment: This looks strange to me, because if the single replica in DC1 goes down, the load will be transfered to DC2 which is not sized for that purpose and may crash as well (domino effect). Replication tackles 2 problems: data safety (no data loss in case of crash) *and* performance (load balancing)

Comment: You are seeing an escape condition created in CASSANDRA-7507 if Cassandra OOMs it now automatically kills the JVM instead of attempting a clean shutdown. 

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7507

I would recommend you use a tool like visual VM to check out your memory and GC as you increase the DC1 load and tell us what you see.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify Consistency Level of LOCAL_ONE you are telling Cassandra to consider the write request successful as soon as one of the local replicas has received the update. However, the request is still sent to ALL replicas. The nodes in the other DC are getting the request at the same time. Due to network latency, the actual work from the request will likely be done shortly after the write request indicates it has successfully completed -- I'm guessing this is the source of the "random" timing of the death of the other DC. Essentially, one or more nodes in that cluster are getting over-loaded.

TL;DR: LOCAL_ONE for writes is essentially identical to ONE. LOCAL_ONE only has significant impact on reads, where only the local DC will be queried (avoiding network costs). The cluster described above is hitting its throughput cap in DC2.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.
Just to give you an update about the case, we changed the RF for 2 on DC1 and 1 on DC2 and everything started to work.
Apparently DC2 was not able to handle the amount of requests coming from DC1... Anyway, we could't identify what was the root cause of the problem, I mean, if it was Heap, IO... what we noticed is that the network traffic was really huge on DC2 before the changes, so maybe this is the problem.